# git branch and merging

Tags: git

I am tryin gto understand branches in git.I have worked with SVN so trying to get the directory structures

i create a  git main repo with

```
mkdir git_repo
cd git_repo
git init --bare
cd ../
git clone git_repo new_clone
cd new_clone
touch test.txt
git add test.txt
git commit test.txt
git push origin master
//So now the contents are in git_repo
git branch new_branch
git branch 
/*master
*new_branch is the output */
git checkout new_branch
//Switched to branch 'new'
```

My question is that

1.How to switch back to new_clone

2.how to push files to new_repo from the branch

3.How can i see the diff in files beteen the new_branch and new_clone

4.How can i push the files to git_repo

5.When i do use merge in this case

6.How to list the files in new_branch and new_clone separately

Can any one please explain these with the examples.

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You cannot "switch back to `new_clone`", because `new_clone` is not a branch. You have a repository with two branches, named `master` and `new_branch`. What does "switch to [repository path]" mean?
2. I think what you mean to ask here is "how do I retrieve commits made to `git_repo` into my working copy in `new_clone`?" The answer is you do a `git fetch` to retrieve the changes, and `git merge` or `git rebase` to incorporate them locally (or `git pull` to do both in one operation).
3. `git diff new_branch new_clone`. For a particular file, `git diff new_branch:path/to/file new_clone:path/to/file`. For the diff in terms of changesets, not patch format, use `git log --oneline --left-right new_clone...new_branch` or the like.
4. `git push`, as you already did.
5. Use merge when you want to incorporate one branch's changes and history into another branch. Merging is a very powerful concept, but you should already be familiar with the basic idea from SVN - git tends to work better, though, because it takes better account of shared ancestry between the revisions to be merged even in a 2-way.

Comment: 1.switch to repo meant that i wanted to make changes from the new_clone and not from its branch 2.how to make changes in the branch and then push to new_clone

Comment: @Rajeev Use `git checkout` to put yourself on whatever branch you like.

Answer (score 0):

GIT is different from SVN - it is a distributed version control system. Don't think of it like SVN with a server and multiple clients, rather it helps to think of it in terms of peer to peer.

Let me first answer your questions:

1. Switching back:

   There is no question of switching back to new_clone - new_clone is a repository and not a branch, the branches are master and new_branch as is listed by `git branch`. If you want to switch to master (the original branch) use: `git checkout master` or in general `git checkout <branch-name>`.
2. You can use `git push origin new_branch` to push a branch to origin.
3. As described in (1) there is no `new_clone` branch. Use this: `git diff new_branch master`
4. See (2)
5. You don't use merge in this case. But let's say you have 2 working copies and you want to share code among them, you can use git merge to merge changes from one copy into another.

Let us look at a full run to help you understand all the concepts. Alice and Bob are 2 users (peers) who are using GIT:

Create 2 users Alice and Bob

```
sudo adduser alice 
sudo adduser bob
```

Login as Alice and configure

```
su alice 
git config --global user.name "Alice" 
git config --global user.email alice@example.com
```

Login as Bob and configure

```
su bob 
git config --global user.name "Bob" 
git config --global user.email bob@example.com
```

Alice creates a GIT repository

```
mkdir project 
cd project/ 
git init 
echo "Some text" > test 
git add test 
git commit -m "Adding test" 
git status
```

Bob clones it, edits and commits changes

```
cd ~
git clone /home/alice/project myclone 
cd myclone/ 
git log # See the changes from Alice
echo "Some text - edited by Bob" > test 
git commit -m "Making changes to test" -a 
git diff
```

Alice merges changes from bob

```
git remote add bob /home/bob/myclone 
git fetch bob 
git branch -a # To list
git log -p master..bob/master 
git merge --no-ff bob/master # Merge changes from Bob
```

Alice makes changes on an experimental branch and then commits it:

```
git branch experimental 
git branch # To list
git checkout experimental 
git branch # To list
echo "Some text - edited by Bob, further edited by Alice" > test 
git commit -m "Further modifying test" -a 
git checkout master 
git log -p master..experimental 
git merge --no-ff experimental 
git branch -d experimental # To delete the branch
```

Bob pulls the changes:

```
git pull
```

Note that there is no central server here, Alice and Bob are peers.

More details here:

- http://book.git-scm.com/3_distributed_workflows.html
- http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/